# netsh show wlan profiles without other stuff

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So I wanted to make a something for practice sake, and because it is a tool I need in my daily life and shouldn't be too hard.
So from googling around I managed to printout my ipadress without showing all other ipconfig stuff by suing this:

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set ip=%%b
set ip=%ip:~1%
echo Your Ipv4 Adress is: %ip%
cmd /k
```

Now I want something similar with
    netsh wlan show profiles

where it only shows the profiles and nothing else so I tried the same thing so I wrote this

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profiles^|find "User profiles"') do set wifi=%%b
set wifi=%wifi:~1%
echo %wifi%
cmd /k
```

But it just shuts opens cmd, as if I opened it manually without writing something.

if someone could explain me where I am making the mistake as the first one works the second doesn't I'd appreciate it

Comment: The `FIND` command is case sensitive.  Are you sure the command outputs as **User profiles** and not **User Profile**. Mine does not output an **s**. Also your code will only grab the last wireless profile.  Is it your intention to output all the wireless profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code can be biased based on other adapters on your network, I will show you a better way to grab the IPv4. This can be very tricky to do as you have to sort through each adapter, In your example it will only grab the **last** one on the `ipconfig` list.

To fix this you can first find the adapter then find the very next ipv4 associated with that adapter. In many cases the ipv4 you will want will be named `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi`. Be sure to change that to your respected network adapter. In the batch script, `%adress%` will be the `IPv4` string.

**Find IPv4 Script BATCH:**

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "adapter=Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi"
set adapterfound=false
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=:" %%f in ('ipconfig') do (
    set "item=%%f"
    if /i "!item!"=="!adapter!" (
        set adapterfound=true
    ) else if not "!item!"=="!item:IPv4 Address=!" if "!adapterfound!"=="true" (
        set "adress=%%g"
        set adress=!adress:* =%!
        set adapterfound=false
    )
)

echo Your IPv4 Address: %adress%

pause
goto :EOF
```

For finding just the profile names with `netsh wlan show profiles`, the proper way will be to utilize the `for loop` with `tokens` & `skip`.

Since the begging lines are always the same for `netsh wlan show profiles`, we can just skip the first 4 lines then use tokens to grab only everything *after* the 4'th space (In our case that is the network profile name). Bellow, the variable `%%b` will be your wi-fi name.

**Grab Only Profile Names BATCH:**

```
@echo off

Rem | Grab all profile names
for /f "tokens=4,* skip=4" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile') do (
    echo [WIFI-NAME: %%b]
)

pause
goto :EOF
```

Using this method, we can even further this to also grab each password with the profile name using `netsh wlan show profile "NAME" key^=clear` and extract the `Key Content` or `->` password. Using a series of `for loops` this can be done clean and organized. The `REM`'s bellow will further explain the process.

**List Profile + Password BATCH:**

```
@echo off

Rem | Grab all profiles
for /f "tokens=4,* skip=4" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile') do (

    Rem | Grab key for each profile
    for /f "tokens=*" %%c in ('netsh wlan show profile "%%b" key^=clear') do (

        Rem | Grab only key
        for /f "tokens=3,*" %%d in ('echo %%c^| find /i "Key Content"') do (

            Rem | Display & Record key
            echo [WIFI-NAME: %%b] [CURRENT-PASSWORD: %%e]

        )
    )
)

pause
goto :EOF
```

For help on any of the commands do the following:

- call /?
- set /?
- for /?
- if /?
- So on.